# Code that runs in Python 2.7 breaks with Python 3.5.1

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have Python Code that runs fine with Python 2.7 but when i run it with Python 3 it doesn't work properly:

```
import sys, os, hashlib

dir_name = sys.argv[1]

# Get the total number of args passed to the crawler.py and set default
# directory
def check_arguments():
    global dir_name
    total = len(sys.argv)
    if total > 2:
        print("Bitte geben Sie nur ein Argument als Startverzeichnis an.")
        sys.exit()
    elif total == 2:
        try:
            os.listdir(dir_name)
            print("Startverzeichnis " + dir_name + " wird verwendet.")
        except:
            print("Geben Sie ein gültiges Startverzeichnis an.")
            sys.exit()
    else:
        print("Startverzeichnis /tmp wird verwendet.")
        dir_name = '/tmp'

def create_MD5(dir_name):
    file_list = []
    hash_list = []
    for file in os.listdir(dir_name):
        try:
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_name, file)):
                print("Folgende Datei gefunden: " , os.path.join(dir_name, file))
                file_list.append(file)
                hash = hashlib.md5.new()
                f = open(os.path.join(dir_name, file),'rb')
                hash.update(f.read())
                f.close()
                hash_list.append(hash.digest())

            elif os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dir_name, file)):
                print("Folgendes Verzeichnis gefunden:", os.path.join(dir_name, file))
                #print_files()
                fl, hl = create_MD5(os.path.join(dir_name, file))
                for i in fl:
                    file_list.append(i)
                for i in hl:
                    hash_list.append(i)
            else:
                pass
        except:
            print("Fehlende Zugriffsrechte")

    return file_list, hash_list

def print_MD5():
    fl, hl = create_MD5(dir_name)
    for i in range(len(fl)):
        print(os.path.join("Die Datei ", '%-22s  hat folgenden MD5-Hash: %s' % (fl[i], hl[i])))

check_arguments()
print_MD5()
```

in the console i got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crawler.py", line 77, in <module>
    print_MD5()
  File "crawler.py", line 74, in print_MD5
    print(os.path.join("Die Datei ", '%-22s  hat folgenden MD5-Hash: %s' % (fl[i], hl[i])))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can i change the code so that it runs with Python 3, too?

Comment: Is that stack trace the only output your program produces? In particular, does it ever print "Fehlende Zugriffsrechte" before that point?

Comment: `print_MD5` uses the global `dir_name` but does not declare it as such.

Comment: Can you add the lines `print(fl)` and `print(hl)` before the `for` loop in `print_MD5()` to see which list is causing the problem?

Comment: @ScottHunter, that's all right. The `global` statement is only necessary if you want to assign something to the global name.

Comment: `hl` appears to be shorter than `fl`

Comment: @TimPietzcker, with print(hl) i got an empty list, print(fl) is a list with files.

Comment: Then Tom Rees' answer is correct - an error occurred between the generation of the two lists, and since you did something bad (using a bare `except` which masks *all* errors, not just those caused by missing access permissions), your program didn't notice that problem. And you possibly even missed the error message your `except` clause was supposed to print because you didn't flush `stdout` - `print("Fehlende Zugriffsrechte", flush=True)` would have avoided that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line:

```
hashlib.md5.new()
```

is incorrect and should be:

```
hashlib.md5()
```

This is throwing an error which your exception eating code is eating. This is why a general `except:` that simply continues regardless is a bad idea, especially in a case such as yours where this potentially leaves the program in a bad state.

Why this works on 2.7 I do not know but I have suspicion it may not be doing what you think it is doing.

Also since hashlib in 3.x reseeds the hash when it it created you would be better off creating a single instance with known hash.

Answer (score 2):

Your 'f1' list is longer than your 'h1' list.

How it reached that state is hard to tell from the code. My guess is that some point after calling file_list.append(), you hit an exception before calling hash_list.append. Possibly in the 'f = open(...)' line.

Refactor the create_MD5 code to ensure no exceptions happen between the two appends and it should be fixed.

**Edit**
As to the reason this works in 2.7 and not 3.5. My guess is it's related to the following from the [Python 3 'Whatsnew'](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html)

> Files opened as text files (still the default mode for open()) always use an encoding to map between strings (in memory) and bytes (on disk). Binary files (opened with a b in the mode argument) always use bytes in memory. This means that if a file is opened using an incorrect mode or encoding, I/O will likely fail loudly, instead of silently producing incorrect data

Or, more likely - see Jack's answer.

Comment: I agree that this is the most likely cause of the problem, but I'm curious why it only happens in 3.5 and not in 2.7.

Comment: in 2.7 i used md5 and for 3 i removed the import md5